# How to add Swagger to a Play framework project

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger

I have a Play project and need to add Swagger to it. Started following this guide: [play-swagger](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger) and even did the[alternative setup](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger/blob/master/docs/AlternativeSetup.md) steps, but the swagger page is empty. Just a header appears on the page. Where should I look for mistakes or did I miss something?

Also, there is another guide: [Swagger UI and Play Framework](http://ainsightful.com/index.php/2017/12/09/how-to-add-swagger-ui-to-a-play-application/), but the sbt cannot resolve the given dependency. Does it need a specific resolver?

I've added this dependency:

```
"org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.2.0"
```

and this sbt plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.iheart" %% "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.7.5")
```

(Play version 2.6, sbt version 1.x, Scala version 2.12.x)
There is a `swagger.yml` file in the `conf` folder. The contents of the Swagger UI dist folder is in the `public/swagger` folder. The routes file contains these lines:

```
### NoDocs ###
GET   /docs/swagger-ui/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path:String="/public/lib/swagger-ui", file:String)

### NoDocs ###
GET   /assets/swagger.json          controllers.swagger.ApiSpecs.specs
```

from alternative setup and the controller class specified in the same guide is also present. The Swagger UI index.hml contatins this line:

```
url: "http://localhost:9000/assets/swagger.json"
```

Comment: Please add to the question Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that reproduces your problem. It's hard to guess where you problem might be without it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To make it work you need 2 things. First, expose an endpoint that responds with swagger.json. Second, to expose a swagger UI, like this one https://petstore.swagger.io/ that goes to take a response from here: https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json. In which of these steps did you stuck?

Comment: The swagger.json endpoint is there. I added the url in the index.htnl as per the guide suggested and tried other values as well. Maybe that url could be the source of the issue, not sure.

Comment: Try to go on something like http://localhost:9000/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/docs/swagger.json What do you see?

Comment: The same empty swagger page as before. There is a swagger header, below that completely blank.

Comment: OK, I found the root of the problem. It happens that Play turns on a security feature and this blocks the Swagger UI. Link: https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger/issues/174